# JSONObject Can't Resolve my error

Tags: java, json

I have my following json file :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "gid": "4",
            "name": "name"
       }
    ]
}
```

To parse my json file, I have this code:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject("/json/test.json");   
JSONArray lg = j.getJSONArray("data");
for(Object g : lg){
    //code
}
```

I get this as error:

```
A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I didn't understand the error because my json file follow already the structure of a JSONObject!

Have someone any idea?

Comment: From which library/package `JSONObject` comes from?

Comment: @Pshemo from  org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: It looks like `new JSONObject("...")` doesn't expect path to JSON file, but string containing JSON structure. Try reading content of that file to string and then pass it as argument.

Comment: I tried this because the user choose the json file :         JSONObject j = new JSONObject(file.getInputStream());
And Now it show me this : org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["data"] not found. I can't understand because data it's a jsonArray

Comment: `new JSONObject(file.getInputStream());` doesn't do what you think it does. It treats passed object as bean, so it will try to create its `getFoo`, `isFoo` methods to create JSON with similar structure, but InputStream doesn't have any of such methods. If you want to use org.json library I am afraid you will need to manually read text from file, store it in string and then parse it with JSONObject.